# Exit code from a batch file is not propagated to the parent powershell script

Tags: powershell

Please, observe:

**c:\temp\1.cmd**

```
@echo off
setlocal

cmd /c dir aaa
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO fail
GOTO end
:fail
echo - Script failed

:end
endlocal
```

Now if I run it in the command prompt:

```
C:\temp> cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.967]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\temp>c:\temp\1.cmd
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4A5E-F223

 Directory of C:\temp

File Not Found
- Script failed

C:\temp>echo %errorlevel%
1

C:\temp>
```

Now I am running it from Powershell:

```
C:\temp> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.16299.967
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.16299.967
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


C:\temp> cmd /c C:\temp\1.cmd
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4A5E-F223

 Directory of C:\temp

File Not Found
- Script failed
C:\temp> $LASTEXITCODE
0
C:\temp>
```

From what I know the exit code is supposed to propagate correctly. So, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: [ERRORLEVEL is not %ERRORLEVEL%](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080926-00/?p=20743).

Second, the errorlevel is not the same as a process exit code.

Try altering your cmd script as follows (note the addition of "exit /b 1"):

```
@echo off
setlocal

cmd /c dir aaa
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO fail
GOTO end
:fail
echo - Script failed
exit /b 1

:end
endlocal
```

Comment: I will accept it, but it seems a bit strange, because `dir` does set the environment variable `%ERRORLEVEL%`. May be it is in addition to the ERRORLEVEL, but nonetheless, the environment variable is set. So, it is in effect the exit code.

Answer (score 7):

<sup>Note: This answer was substantially rewritten after new information came to light.</sup>

To complement [jazzdelightsme's effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55289640/45375) with some **general guidance and background information**:

- **When calling a batch file from *outside* `cmd.exe`**, such as **from PowerShell, invoke it as `cmd /c 'file.cmd ... & exit'`** or - if string interpolation is needed - as 
  **`cmd /c "file.cmd ... & exit"`**, which then requires escaping *embedded* `"` as `` `" ``<sup>[1]</sup>. This ensures that it behaves as it would when called from *inside* `cmd.exe` with respect to its exit code (error level), i.e. **ensures that the batch file's exit code *reliably* becomes `cmd.exe`'s *process* exit code**.

  - [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66975883/45375) explains the problem and this - obscure - workaround in detail.
  - **Note**: The simpler workaround based on `call` - `cmd /c call file.cmd ...` - works *in principle*, but has an *unwanted side effect* when (of necessity double-quoted<sup>[2]</sup>) arguments with `^` characters are passed: Due to use of `call`, **`^` characters** ("carets", strictly speaking *circumflex accents*, [`U+005E`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5e)) are ***invariably doubled***, so that say, argument `"a ^ 2"`, is seen by the batch file as `"a ^^ 2"`; it is unclear what the purpose of this behavior is, but it has seemingly always existed - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66250528/45375) for details on `cmd.exe`'s parser.
- *Without* the `& exit` workaround, you'll only get the desired behavior if you ensure that *all* code paths exit in one of the following ways - and missing a code path is an easy mistake to make:

  - `exit` with *no* arguments, which correctly relays the most recently executed command's exit code.

    - **Caveat**: `exit` *without `/b`* instantly exits the `cmd.exe` instance as a whole, so it isn't suitable for use inside batch files that may be run interactively or must be callable from *other* batch files and return control to those batch files.
  - `exit /b <code>` or `exit <code>`, where `<code>` represents the desired exit code, i.e. specifying an *explicit* exit code, as in jazzdelightsme's solution.

    - **Caveat**: Exiting a batch file with `exit /b` *without an explicit `<code>` argument* does *not* pass the most recently executed command's exit code through without the `` cmd /c <batch-file> ... `& exit `` workaround - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66250528/45375).

---

**Additional background information**, in the context of **your code**:

Bizarrely, with an *outside* invocation of a batch file *without `& exit` (or `call`)*, statements such as `if`, `goto`, `echo`, and `endlocal`, and even `REM` (but, curiously, not `::`) *reset the exit code that `cmd.exe` later reports to `0`* - even though *inside* that `cmd.exe` session `%ERRORLEVEL%` is set as it usually is, meaning that such statements have no impact on the current `%ERRORLEVEL%` value.

Therefore:

- When your batch file is run from *inside* `cmd.exe`, the specific statements that follow the command that sets `%ERRORLEVEL%` to `1` (`cmd /c dir aaa`), i.e. the `if`, `goto`, `echo` and `endlocal` statements, *preserve* this value, and `%ERRORLEVEL%` ends up with value `1` after exiting the batch file.

  - Bizarrely, the error level is set only *after* the statement involving the batch file call, so that something like `file.cmd || exit` does *not* work, because the `||` operator doesn't recognize the `file.cmd` call as having failed. This is the reason that the workaround uses `&` rather than `||`.
- When your batch file is run from *outside* `cmd.exe`, and *isn't* invoked with `cmd /c "<batch-file> ... & exit"` (or `cmd /c call <batch-file> ...`), the same statements that follow the `%ERRORLEVEL%`-setting command suddenly reset the exit code that `cmd.exe` itself later reports to `0`, instead of preserving the post-batch-file-execution `%ERRORLEVEL%` value.

---

<sup>[1] *Situationally*, you can get away with `` cmd /c <batch-file> ... `& exit ``, i.e. without enclosing the arguments to `/c` in a single, overall string, but that *breaks* if the batch-file path needs double-quoting *and* at least one double-quoted pass-through argument is also present.</sup>

<sup>[2] `^` chars. in *unquoted* arguments, as usual, are interpreted as `cmd.exe`'s *escape character* and therefore *removed*.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know why but I had the same problem.
$LastExitCode was always 0 even if the batch file exited with an errorCode of 1.

I needed the $LastExitCode so that in case of error, I had to prompt an error an exit the ps1 script, so what I did was **wrapping the batch execution command inside an if** like this:

```
if( !(Start-Process -FilePath PATH/TO/BATCH -NoNewWindow -Wait -ErrorAction -Stop -ArgumentList arguments_if_needed) ){
   
    Write-Error "There was an error, exiting"
    exit
}
```

This is working for me.