# Call a batch file from PowerShell with proper exit code reporting while avoiding doubling of carets

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, parameter-passing, exit-code

I suspect there is no good solution, but perhaps I'm overlooking something:

What I'm after is a way to:

- (a) call a batch file from PowerShell in a way that *robustly* reflects its - implicit or explicit - exit code in PowerShell's automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable.

  - Notably, calling a batch file that exits with, say, `whoami -nosuch || exit /b`, should result in `$LASTEXITCODE` reflecting `whoami`'s exit code, i.e. `1`. This is *not* the case when you invoke a batch file (by name or path) from PowerShell: the exit code is `0` (by contrast, inside a `cmd.exe` session `%ERRORLEVEL%` *is* set to `1`).
  - Also note that the invocation should remain integrated with PowerShell's output streams, so I am *not* looking for solutions based on [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process).
  - Furthermore, I have *no* knowledge of or control over the batch files getting invoked - I'm looking for a generic solution.
- (b) without double-quoted arguments passed to the batch file getting altered in any way, and without `cmd.exe`'s behavior getting modified in any way; notably:

  - `^` characters should *not* be doubled (see below).
  - Enabling *delayed expansion* with `/V:ON` is *not* an option.

---

The only way I know how to solve (a) is to invoke the batch file via `cmd /c call`.

Unfortunately, this violates requirement (b), because the use of `call` seemingly *invariably doubles `^` characters* in arguments. (And, conversely, *not* using `call` then doesn't report the exit code reliably).

Is there a way to satisfy *both* requirements?

Note that PowerShell is only the messenger here: The problem lies with `cmd.exe`, and anyone calling a batch file from outside a `cmd.exe` session is faced with the same problem.

---

Example (PowerShell code):

```
# Create a (temporary) batch file that echoes its arguments,
# provokes an error, and exits with `exit /b` *without an explicit argument*.
'@echo off & echo [%*] & whoami -nosuch 2>NUL || exit /b' | Set-Content test.cmd

# Invoke the batch file and report the exit code.
.\test.cmd "a ^ 2"; $LASTEXITCODE
```

**The output *should be*:**

```
["a ^ 2"]
1
```

However, in reality the exit code is *not* reported:

```
["a ^ 2"]
0          # !! BROKEN
```

If I call with `cmd /c call .\test.cmd` instead, the exit code is correct, but the `^` characters are doubled:

```
PS> cmd /c call .\test.cmd "a ^ 2"; $LASTEXITCODE
["a ^^ 2"]  # !! BROKEN
1           # OK
```

Comment: This works for me: `cmd '/c .\test.cmd "a ^ 2" & exit /b'` . It returns correct output from your test batch file and if I put gibberish there I get `9009` in `$LASTEXITCODE` (`MSG_DIR_BAD_COMMAND_OR_FILE`).

Comment: That's great, @beatcracker - please post it as an answer, and I'll accept it. I had tried `|| exit /b`, which _should_ work; trying `& exit /b` hadn't even occurred to me - it suggests that `cmd.exe` itself isn't aware that the batch file failed, yet somehow does pass its nonzero exit code through with `exit /b`. ‍♂️

Comment: You mentioning that the `%ERRORLEVEL% is set to 1` gave me a hint that something like this _might_ work ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've no idea why this works, but it does:

```sh
cmd /c '.\test.cmd "a ^ 2" & exit'
$LASTEXITCODE
```

Output:

```
["a ^ 2"] 
1
```

Answer (score 3):

**Kudos to [beatcracker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4424236/beatcracker) for finding an effective workaround in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66977017/45375)**; let me add some **background information and guidance**:

- First, to be clear, no workaround should be necessary; **`cmd.exe`'s behavior is clearly a bug.**
- `cmd /c '.\test.cmd "a ^ 2" || exit'` - i.e. `||` rather than `&` - is what one would expect to be an effective workaround too. The fact that only `&`, which *unconditionally* sequences commands, works, indicates that even `cmd.exe`-*internally* the failure status of the batch file isn't yet known *as part of the same statement* - only *afterwards* - which appears to be another manifestation of the bug.

  - Why an *explicit* `exit` call following the batch-file call as part of the same statement *does* relay the batch file's (zero or nonzero) exit code correctly is anyone's guess, but it seems to work.
- Fortunately, the workaround is also effective for solving related exit-code problems in batch files that do *not* contain explicit `exit /b` / `exit` calls - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55290133/45375).

**Syntax considerations**:

- From PowerShell, the alternative to passing a *single* command-string is to pass *individual arguments* and *escape* the `&` character as `` `& `` (using `` ` ``, the "backtick", PowerShell's escape character) so as to prevent *PowerShell* from interpreting it (*quoting* it as `'&'` would work too):

  ```
  cmd /c .\test.cmd "a ^ 2" `& exit
  ```
- From an environment that *doesn't involve a shell*, such as when launching from Task Scheduler, the `` ` ``-escaping of `&` is *not* needed (and mustn't be used).

Not having to enclose the *entire* for-`cmd.exe` command in quotes makes it easier to pass arguments that (a) *individually* require double quotes and (b) involve references to *PowerShell* variables and/or expressions, given that the latter requires use of `"..."` rather than `'...'`:

```
# Passing *individual* arguments makes double-quoting easier.
PS> cmd /c .\test.cmd "Version = $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)" `& exit; $LASTEXITCODE
["Version = 7.2.0-preview.4"]
1
```

Using quoting of the *entire* for-`cmd.exe` command would be awkward in this case, due to the need to escape the argument-specific `"` chars.:

```
# Embedded double quotes must now be `-escaped.
PS> cmd /c ".\test.cmd `"Version = $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)`" & exit"
["Version = 7.2.0-preview.4"]
1
```

---

The **[`Native`](https://github.com/mklement0/Native) module** (authored by me; install it [from the PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Native) with `Install-Module Native`) comes with **function `ie`**, which:

- **automatically applies the above workaround**.
- generally compensates for problems arising from PowerShell's broken argument-passing to external programs (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375)).

```
# After having run Install-Module Native:
# Use of function `ie` applies the workaround behind the scenes.
PS> ie .\test.cmd "Version = $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)"; $LASTEXITCODE
["Version = 7.2.0-preview.4"]
1
```

The hope is that what function `ie` does will become a part of PowerShell itself, as part of the upcoming (in PowerShell v7.2) `PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing` experimental feature that is intended as an opt-in fix to the broken argument-passing - see [GitHub issue #15143](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15143)