# How to call a batch file from Powershell, using a custom .cmd to run it?

Tags: powershell

I need to run the following batch file:

```
cd ..
msbuild reve_host.vcxproj
```

In order for msbuild to work, it needs to be run through a specific shell. Its path is stored in $executorPath in my Powershell script, which looks like this:

```
$executorPath = 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2019\Visual Studio Tools\VC\x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019'
Write-Host "STAGE: CLEAN."
```

Here are several ways of executing that I have tried, that have not worked:

1. `Invoke-Command '$executorPath "BUILD.bat"'`
2. `Invoke-Command '$executorPath ".\BUILD.bat"'`
3. `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& $executorPath 'BUILD.bat'}`
4. `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& $executorPath '.\BUILD.bat'}`
5. `$($executorPath 'BUILD.bat')`
6. `$($executorPath '.\BUILD.bat')`

With 1 and 2, I get:

> Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided.

With 3 and 4, I get:

> The term 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2019\Visual Studio Tools\VC\x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

None of these work. How do I run this?

Comment: First of all - you have to concatenate the path and file name with a backslash to make it a full path. And second - a `*.bat` is not an executable - `CMD.exe` is. And bat should be provided as the second argument after `/c` if you want to run it.  Otherwise you would need to use `Invoke-Expression`  ;-)

Comment: Try `. (Join-Path -Path $executorPath -ChildPath BUILD.bat)` or (another approach) `& "$(Join-Path -Path $executorPath -ChildPath BUILD.bat)"` or something alike.

Comment: @Olaf I'm not sure I understand what you mean by concatenate the path and file name. Do you think you could make a full answer explaining you solution more thoroughly? I'm quite new to this :)

Comment: Try JosefZ recommendation! ;-)

Comment: What i mean is `"C:\randomPath\withSubfolder" "fileName.bat"` is not the same like `"C:\randomPath\withSubfolder\fileName.bat"`. Only second one is a valid full path.  ;-)

Comment: @JosefZ With both of your suggestions, I get the same error as is listed in my original post, in "With 3 and 4, I get:"

Comment: This might help ... [Call a batch file from PowerShell....](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66977017/9196560)  .. take a look to the answer. You should `cd` into the folder or provide the complete path of the bat file.

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative solution. Using [this](https://github.com/deadlydog/Invoke-MsBuild) module allows MsBuild to be called directly from Powershell and saves the hassle of manually calling the correct shell. This circumvents the problem, instead of solving it though.

Comment: OMG  ;-)  ... really?  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Or Simply:

```
#Test cmd file:
@Echo off
for %%i in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) DO Echo. Hello there
exit /B 200
```

```
PS> & G:\BEKDocs\Batch\batch1.cmd
 Hello there
 Hello there
 Hello there
 Hello there
 Hello there
 Hello there
 Hello there
 Hello there
 Hello there
 Hello there

#To Use your example code:

PS> $ExecutionPath = "G:\BEKDocs\Batch\batch1.cmd"

PS> & $ExecutionPath
 Hello there
 Hello there
 Hello there
 Hello there
 Hello there
 Hello there
 Hello there
 Hello there
 Hello there
 Hello there

PS>
```

EDIT: It also works if the extension is .bat!