# Run Batch file with Arguments & Return Code in Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

UPDATE: Solved, see comment

I'm trying to run a batch file inside a powershell script, where I need to pass two arguments and read the return code.

I tried and read $LASTEXITCODE, but it always returns me "0".

This doesn't pass the arguments to the batch file:

```
& $BATCH_PATH $REQUIRED_PARAMETERS $OPTIONAL_PARAMETERS | Out-File -FilePath "$COMPARE_DIR\$LOG_FILENAME.log" -Append
```

This works, but LASTEXITCODE is always "0":

```
cmd.exe /c "$($ROOT_DIR)\batch.bat $REQUIRED_PARAMETERS $OPTIONAL_PARAMETERS" | Out-File -FilePath "$COMPARE_DIR\$LOG_FILENAME.log" -Append
```

This works, but LASTEXITCODE is always "0":

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c", "$BATCH_PATH", "$REQUIRED_PARAMETERS", "$OPTIONAL_PARAMETERS" -WindowStyle Hidden -PassThru -Wait -RedirectStandardOutput "$COMPARE_DIR\$(Get-Random).log"
```

I also tried to get the ExitCode-Property of the Process-Object, but it is also 0.

Comment: I solved the issue after adding "exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%" to my batch file

Comment: Then create an answer or delete your question.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

Rather than having to modify *your batch file* by adding an `exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%` statement, you can modify the batch file's *invocation* by appending  `& exit` in order to achieve the same effect:

```
cmd.exe /c "$($ROOT_DIR)\batch.bat $REQUIRED_PARAMETERS $OPTIONAL_PARAMETERS & exit" | 
  Out-File -FilePath "$COMPARE_DIR\$LOG_FILENAME.log" -Append
```

This obscure solution is necessitated by the unfortunate fact that **`cmd.exe` doesn't reliably relay a *batch file's* exit code as *its process exit code* when the batch file is called *from the outside***, neither when a batch file is called directly nor via `cmd.exe /c` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55290133/45375) for details.

Note:

- The `ie` function that comes with the [`Native`](https://github.com/mklement0/Native) module (`Install-Module Native`) *automatically* applies this workaround, so that invocation as
  `ie "$($ROOT_DIR)\batch.bat" ...` would work as-is with respect to setting `$LASTEXITCODE` (though you'd have to pass the arguments individually or via *array* variables, as discussed).
- [GitHub proposal #15143](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15143) advocates building this workaround into PowerShell itself, as part of a larger proposal to improve argument-passing to external programs on Windows, but the proposal [was rejected](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15143#issuecomment-833090452).

---

As for **what you tried**:

> This doesn't pass the arguments to the batch file:
>
> ```
> & $BATCH_PATH $REQUIRED_PARAMETERS $OPTIONAL_PARAMETERS`
> ```

This syntax works *in principle*, but not if your variables contain *multiple* arguments as a *single string*. E.g., `$REQUIRED_PARAMETERS = 'foo bar'` would *not* work, but specifying the arguments a an an *array* of strings would, `$REQUIRED_PARAMETERS = 'foo', 'bar'`: In the former case, `'foo bar'` is passed *as a single argument*, in the latter case, the *array elements* become *individual* arguments.

> This works, but LASTEXITCODE is always "0":
>
> ```
> Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c", "$BATCH_PATH", "$REQUIRED_PARAMETERS", "$OPTIONAL_PARAMETERS" -WindowStyle Hidden -PassThru -Wait -RedirectStandardOutput "$COMPARE_DIR\$(Get-Random).log"
> ```
>
> I also tried to get the ExitCode-Property of the Process-Object, but it is also 0.

The [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE`  variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) is only set for *direct* calls to external programs, not when you use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) - which is [generally the wrong tool for invoking *console* applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334633/45375).

(As your statement implies, it is possible to get a process' exit code when `Start-Process` is used, namely by adding `-Wait -PassThru` to the call in order to wait for the process to exit and to return a [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) instance whose exit code can then be inspected.

In the case at hand this wouldn't make a difference anyway, because the problem lies with `cmd.exe` itself, not with how it is invoked.)