# Unexpected exit code when running a batch file from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I am calling a `.bat` file from `Powershell` in a Microsoft Windows environment, and would like to know if the exit code was success or failure.

A problem seems to be occurring in this unusual, *(although not very unusual)*, edge-case.

Example #1:

.\test1.bat

```
ECHO ON
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
False
if !errorlevel! neq 0 exit /b !errorlevel!
echo "More text"
```

This works fine. `False` causes an error; the next line checks the status, sees a `1`, and `exit`s with code `1`.  The calling `powershell` has the correct result. `echo $LASTEXITCODE` is  `1`.

Example #2:

.\test2.bat

```
ECHO ON
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if "testing" == "testing" (
    False
    if !errorlevel! neq 0 exit /b !errorlevel!
    echo "More text"
    echo "More code"
    True
    if !errorlevel! neq 0 exit /b !errorlevel!
    echo "More code"
)
```

Here is the difficulty. `False` causes an error; the next line checks the status, sees a `1`, and exits with code `1`.  Then, the calling `powershell` has an unexpected result, `echo $LASTEXITCODE` is `0`.

Could only the batch file be modified to fix the problem?

Comment: How exactly do you call the batch file?

Comment: @aschipfl simply .\test1.bat

Comment: @KJ The reason for having the line "if !errorlevel! neq 0 exit /b !errorlevel!" is to somewhat mimic "set -e" on bash.  That is, run various commands and exit right in the middle of the batch file if an error has been found.   Wrapping the remainder of the file in an "else" statement (actually, many repeating else statements) would not be very elegant...

Comment: @KJ "give a truer snippet". Ok, I have slightly modified the original snippet.  The intention is to be able to have more logic, more lines of code, and still at any point include a "check the errorlevel and exit", if something failed.

Comment: For your examples `If ErrorLevel 1` is probably a better fit than `if !errorlevel! neq 0`, unless there is really negative errorlevels being reported. However `False` is not a command and neither is `True`, so I'm not sure why your using different strings there. BTW what happens if you use `Exit !ErrorLevel!`, without the `/B` option.

Comment: @Compo, without the /B option solves it.   Then, the question is, if that's the "right" solution. Why is that necessary?  Maybe it's the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing problematic `cmd.exe` behavior **when *batch files* are called from *outside* `cmd.exe`**, such as from PowerShell, **their exit codes aren't *reliably* relayed as `cmd.exe`'s  *process* exit code**.

For background information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55290133/45375).

**Workarounds**:

- Call your batch file as follows:

  ```
  cmd /c '.\test2.bat & exit'
  ```
- Alternatively, if installing a third-party module (authored by me) is an option, use the `ie` function from the [`Native`](https://github.com/mklement0/Native) module (`Install-Module Native`), which additionally compensates for PowerShell's broken argument-passing to external programs (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375)):

  ```
  # Assuming `Install-Module Native` was run:
  ie .\test2.bat
  ```